# How can I retrieve a user's email with Facebook Graph API when they are in professional mode?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

is there a way to return the email in facebook graph api if the account is currently in professional mode?

when i tried to remove the professional mode in my account, it was able to return the email. but when in professional mode it return a message that

`The email field was not returned. This may be because the email was missing, invalid or hasn't been confirmed.`

Comment: What do you mean by "professional mode"?

Comment: facebook have a feature where their personal accounts can be made to professional mode. this is similar to content creator. you can turn it on by going to your profile page then clicking the 3 dots and selecting turn on professional mode